# FB: System user access token don't have scope delegated from configuration from FB login for Business flow

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login, facebook-business-sdk

Steps I followed:

- Create app
- Add FB login for Business product in your app
- Create config with permission & asset I selected - Adaccount, Page, Pixel

```
Javascript SDK
window.FB.login(
(response) => {
 if (response && response.authResponse && response.authResponse.accessToken) {
    console.log("################")
    console.log(response);
    console.log("################")
 }
},
{
   config_id: 'your_id', // configuration ID goes here
   response_type: 'code',   // must be set to 'code' for SUAT
   scope: 'business_management,ads_management,pages_read_engagement', // passing extra, tired      without passing as well
   return_scopes: true
}
);
```

On click of a button This will open a authentication pop-up.
Post authentication:
I get **access_token(System user) as well as code**.

Now as per [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/facebook-login-for-business)

Path 1: I'm suppose to use code  through which I can get token, BUT getting error redirect_uri doesn't match.

&

Path 2: If I debug access_token from response
[image: debug access_token]

Scopes I set in configuration settings are not set/delegated to system user.

Following are my configurations:
[image: Following are my configurations]
[image: Response]

Aim is to have access_token of system user so that I can run cron jobs to publish ads.

Comment: So what is the actual URL that it redirects you back to, where you receive the `code` parameter?

Comment: No code is in response

Comment: You already got an access token in the response there, is that _not_ the system user token you wanted?

Comment: The JS SDK's login functionality doesn't normally _use_ a redirect, but the result is passed back to the callback function. I don't know if Facebook implemented anything different for when a `config_id` is specified instead of scopes.

Comment: Has your app requested advanced permissions & been reviewed?

Comment: No app is still in development.